# can 2 versions of an application coexist in mac in same user account

Tags: macos

i am new to mac programming. my applications new version has a different name than the previous version which results in both versions getting installed. i want to delete the previous version when installing new version.

can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: You can have two application binaries, but the problem are incompatible preferences and Application Support files that are always shared between versions, unless you change the Application Support folder name and bundle identifier yourself.

Comment: Why not give the two versions the same name?

Answer (score 1):

In your new app's startup code, move the old app to the trash after telling the user what you're going to do.

Answer (score 0):

but the code of the new version does not get executed because the user writes the name of the application in spotlight, he/she gets the last used version as the top hit and clicks on that and it again ask for an update which leads to a cycle.